# Trace an object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, debugging

Is there a way to trace an object in to the screen ?
I am coming from rails where you can do

```
<%= debug @var %>
```

Is there something similar to angularjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(some_var)` will print the object to your browser's console.

Better yet, use Firebug or Chrome Inspector and debug with breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

use {{ var }} on your html page, then set the var in your controller as $scope.var.